# "Function call missing argument list"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES       //needed to include the math constants
#include <math.h>
#include <string>               //needed to include texts
using namespace std;

double Volume(double Length, double Width, double Height)
{
    double volume;
    volume = Length*Width*Height; 
    return volume;
}

double Area(double Length, double Width, double Height)
{
    double area;
    area = 2 * Width*Length + 2 * Length*Height + 2 * Height*Width; 
    return area;
}

void DisplayData(double Length, double Width, double Height, double volume, double area)
{
    cout << "For the width " << Width << ", the length " << Length << " and the Height " << Height << "; the volume of the box is " << volume << " and the surface area is " << area << ".";
}

int main()
{
    double Length, Width, Height;

    cout << "Welcome! This program will calculate the volume and surface area of a box. All this program needs is you to input the length, width and height of the box." << endl;
    cout << "Please note that all meausurments are in meters." << endl;
    cout << "Please insert a value for the length: " << endl;
    cin >> Length;
    cout << "Please insert a value for the width: " << endl;
    cin >> Width;
    cout << "Please insert a value for the height: " << endl;
    cin >> Height;
    cout << endl;

    Volume;
    Area;
    DisplayData;

    return 0;
}//end main
```

I am writing a program with functions but it gives me the error in the title. How exactly do I call functions? I don't really understand that part. Do you just write the name of the function or is there something else involved?

Comment: [GCC didn't give me any error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8BvTjCwoK6FDsypK), but do you want to call the functions instead of placing meaningless statements that only contain function name?

Comment: Best troll this week to date. Well-formatted question. Meaningful function names, clearly named parameters. Then the punchline. Bravo.

Comment: @MikeCat what do you mean? I don't really understand it

Comment: @SamVarshavchik D: What do you mean? I just have a lot questions and I don't understand a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should call the functions like this

```
double volume = Volume(Length, Width, Height);
double area = Area(Length, Width, Height);
DisplayData(Length, Width, Height, volume, area);
```

instead of the three meaningless statements

```
Volume;
Area;
DisplayData;
```

Comment: Okay, I see now. You want to declare stuff when calling a variable.

Comment: @BobSmith What do you mean?

Comment: @BobSmith Think of a function like a hand-held calculator.  To add two numbers, you don't just press the '+' key and look at the calculator waiting for the answer.  That is basically what you were doing in your original code.  You must also type in the two numbers you want to add.  Those two numbers are the *arguments*.  Same thing here -- the `Volume` requires arguments for it to do something.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks. It makes a lot more sense now. I'll keep that in when writing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Function name and variable name is clashing with each other. Compiler is treating `volume` variable as function and looking for arguments after it.

```
 double volume;
```

Change it to

```
 double dVolume;
 dVolume = Length*Width*Height; 
 return dVolume;
```

Do similar changes for `area` as well.